# Bypassing a switching regulator

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to design a power supply for a 3.3 V / max. 340 mA system.
It should provide the possibility for 5 V-12 V input as well as directly providing 3.3 V. Even though it is not intended to connect both input voltages, the system should not break down in that case (at least it should work again, as soon as only one supply is connected).

My first attempt is using Schottky-Diodes, but this would result in 2.9 V output voltage and not 3.3 V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqROK1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation you would typically design an active switching solution.

First you nominate a primary supply - the supply that is the preferred one. Normally this would be the higher powered supply, so your switching regulator.

If that supply is working, then the secondary supply should be isolated. If it's not working, then the secondary supply should be enabled.

The trick here is to use a component backwards - a P-channel MOSFET.  Connect it in series with the 3.3V input in such a way that its parasitic diode conducts.  This provides a lower (~3V) "trigger" voltage.  You then use that to power an op-amp, which works as a comparator.  The input (5-12V) voltage is then monitored through a resistive divider to ensure it is above a suitable threshold by the op-amp.  If the input voltage is below that threshold then the output of the op-amp enables the P-channel MOSFET, which then causes its parasitic diode to be bypassed by the main channel, thus reducing the voltage drop to near 0.

It's basically how boards like the Arduino UNO etc handle multiple power sources and yet get the full 5V from the USB power input:

[image]

Your equivalent would have USBVCC as your 3.3V input, and +5V would be your intended 3.3V running voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing a little power when using a switching regulator, then this schematic might help. Inspired by Linear Technology battery charger datasheet.

When there is no output from your Switched-Mode Power Supply, M1's gate is grounded so it's opened. Vout = 3.3V. When SMPS is on, the gate goes high (Vgs = 0), closing the transistor. Then the output is fed from a SMPS through a diode.

The weak link here is having to compensate for the diode's voltage drop (hence 3.6V). To make things worse, this drop is not constant over the current range. But then again, if you're just going to power a microcontroller or something similar, then who cares for these 100mV? See Figure 1 here for example: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MBR0520LT1-D.PDF

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foPBYu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>